# How to use OOP to avoid repeating same code over and over?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, oop

I am displaying two different quizzes on the same page. I have a JS function that repeats everything for the second quiz, the only thing different is about 5  variables at the start of the second function.

The issue with this is that if I want to fix something in the core quiz code, I would have to do it twice (or more if later I make more quizzes).

I would like to not repeat the core quiz code over and over, instead supplying only the new variables each time I create a new quiz. I have read about OOP but I still feel like I'm over my head. I was wondering if anyone could supply an example of what I should do.

In the real version of the quizzes I use an external JSON file to store the quiz data. Below I stored it in a variable for simplicity.

Here is the code: http://codepen.io/Jake_Ratliff/pen/QjrqRv?editors=001

Same code here:

HTML:

```
<body>

  <div id='main'>

    <div id="question1"></div>

  </div>
  <br>
  <div id='buttons'>
    <button id='prev' class='button'>Back</button>

    <button id='next' class='button'>Next</button><br><br>
    <button id='restart' class='button'>Start Over?</button>
    <br><br> 
  </div>

  <div id='main2'>

    <div id="question2"></div>

  </div>
  <br>
  <div id='buttons'>
    <button id='prev2' class='button'>Back</button>

    <button id='next2' class='button'>Next</button><br><br>
    <button id='restart2' class='button'>Start Over?</button>
    <br><br> 
  </div>

</body>
```

JS:

```
quiz1();
quiz2();


function quiz1(){

  var allQuestions = [{
  question: "How many presidents were members of the Whig party?",
  choices: ["Four", "Three", "Two"],
  correct: 0
}, {
  question: "Who was the first president to be impeached?",
  choices: ["Andrew Jackson", "Andrew Johnson", "Warren Harding"],
  correct: 1
}, {
  question: "How many presidents died during their presidency?",
  choices: ["Four", "Six", "Eight"],
  correct: 2
}];

var counter = 0;
var main = $("#main");
var question = $("#question1");
var userInputs = [];
var numCorrect = 0;
var fadeSpeed = 700;

var next = $("#next");
var prev = $("#prev");
var restart = $("#restart")

createQDiv();

if (counter == 0) {
  prev.hide();
}

//click handler for Next Question button
next.click(function() {

  var selection = $("input[name=answer]:checked").val();
  if (selection != undefined) {
    choose();
    fadeQuestion();
    setTimeout(function() {
      clearLast();
      counter++;
      //moveProgress();
      prev.show();
      createQDiv();
    }, fadeSpeed);

  } else {
    alert("You must select an answer to proceed.")
  };
});

//creates question element
function createQDiv() {
  //$("#prev").hide();
  question.fadeIn(fadeSpeed);
  main.append(question);
  if (counter <

    allQuestions.length

  ) {
    displayNext();
  } else {
    displayScore();
  }
};

//fade out question element
function fadeQuestion() {
  question.fadeOut(fadeSpeed);
};

//clears question element
function clearLast() {
  question.empty();
};

//adds question and answers to question element
function displayNext() {
  restart.hide();
  var qPara = $("<p>" + allQuestions[counter].question + "</p>")
  question.append(qPara);
  createRadios();
  addPrevSelection();

};

//creates radio buttons for each choice
function createRadios() {
  var choices = allQuestions[counter].choices;
  //var formElement = $("<form></form>");
  //$("#question").append(formElement);
  for (i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
    question.append($("<input type='radio' name='answer' value='" + i + "'>" + choices[i] + "<br>"));
  };
};

//checks user's answer choice and stores in array
function choose() {
  var input = $("input[name=answer]:checked").val();

  userInputs[counter] = input;

};

//create function for checking user's answers vs number correct. output = number of correct answers
function correctAns() {
  for (i = 0; i < allQuestions.length; i++) {
    if (userInputs[i] == allQuestions[i].correct) {
      numCorrect++;
    };
  };
};
//create 'last page' for displaying user's score

function displayScore() {
  next.hide();
  prev.hide();
  correctAns();
  var score = (numCorrect / allQuestions.length);
  //var encouragement;
  var scoreElement = $("<p>You got " + numCorrect + " out of " + allQuestions.length + " correct.</p>");
  $("#question1").append(scoreElement);
  restart.show();
};

prev.click(function() {
  if (counter > 0) {
    fadeQuestion();
    setTimeout(function() {
      clearLast();
      counter--;
      //moveProgress();
      createQDiv();
      addPrevSelection();
      choose();
    }, fadeSpeed);

    //Cristina: what if user changes input and then hits back? It isn't kept, only logged on the next button.
  } else {
    prev.hide();
  }
});

function addPrevSelection() {
  var selection = userInputs[counter];
  var radioSelected = $("input[value='" + selection + "']");
  //alert(radioSelected);
  radioSelected.prop("checked", true);
};

restart.click(function() {
  counter = 0;
  next.show();
  userInputs = [];
  numCorrect = 0;
  clearLast();
  //moveProgress();
  createQDiv();

});

}

function quiz2(){

  var allQuestions = [{
  question: "Sample text for second quiz?",
  choices: ["Four", "Three", "Two"],
  correct: 0
}, {
  question: "Sample text 2 for second quiz?",
  choices: ["Andrew Jackson", "Andrew Johnson", "Warren Harding"],
  correct: 1
}, {
  question: "Sample text 3?",
  choices: ["Four", "Six", "Eight"],
  correct: 2
}];

var counter = 0;
var main = $("#main2");
var question = $("#question2");
var userInputs = [];
var numCorrect = 0;
var fadeSpeed = 700;

var next = $("#next2");
var prev = $("#prev2");
var restart = $("#restart2")

createQDiv();

if (counter == 0) {
  prev.hide();
}

//click handler for Next Question button
next.click(function() {

  var selection = $("input[name=answer]:checked").val();
  if (selection != undefined) {
    choose();
    fadeQuestion();
    setTimeout(function() {
      clearLast();
      counter++;
      //moveProgress();
      prev.show();
      createQDiv();
    }, fadeSpeed);

  } else {
    alert("You must select an answer to proceed.")
  };
});

//creates question element
function createQDiv() {
  //$("#prev").hide();
  question.fadeIn(fadeSpeed);
  main.append(question);
  if (counter <

    allQuestions.length

  ) {
    displayNext();
  } else {
    displayScore();
  }
};

//fade out question element
function fadeQuestion() {
  question.fadeOut(fadeSpeed);
};

//clears question element
function clearLast() {
  question.empty();
};

//adds question and answers to question element
function displayNext() {
  restart.hide();
  var qPara = $("<p>" + allQuestions[counter].question + "</p>")
  question.append(qPara);
  createRadios();
  addPrevSelection();

};

//creates radio buttons for each choice
function createRadios() {
  var choices = allQuestions[counter].choices;
  //var formElement = $("<form></form>");
  //$("#question").append(formElement);
  for (i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
    question.append($("<input type='radio' name='answer' value='" + i + "'>" + choices[i] + "<br>"));
  };
};

//checks user's answer choice and stores in array
function choose() {
  var input = $("input[name=answer]:checked").val();

  userInputs[counter] = input;

};

//create function for checking user's answers vs number correct. output = number of correct answers
function correctAns() {
  for (i = 0; i < allQuestions.length; i++) {
    if (userInputs[i] == allQuestions[i].correct) {
      numCorrect++;
    };
  };
};
//create 'last page' for displaying user's score

function displayScore() {
  next.hide();
  prev.hide();
  correctAns();
  var score = (numCorrect / allQuestions.length);
  //var encouragement;
  var scoreElement = $("<p>You got " + numCorrect + " out of " + allQuestions.length + " correct.</p>");
  question.append(scoreElement);
  restart.show();
};

prev.click(function() {
  if (counter > 0) {
    fadeQuestion();
    setTimeout(function() {
      clearLast();
      counter--;
      //moveProgress();
      createQDiv();
      addPrevSelection();
      choose();
    }, fadeSpeed);

    //Cristina: what if user changes input and then hits back? It isn't kept, only logged on the next button.
  } else {
    prev.hide();
  }
});

function addPrevSelection() {
  var selection = userInputs[counter];
  var radioSelected = $("input[value='" + selection + "']");
  //alert(radioSelected);
  radioSelected.prop("checked", true);
};

restart.click(function() {
  counter = 0;
  next.show();
  userInputs = [];
  numCorrect = 0;
  clearLast();
  //moveProgress();
  createQDiv();

});

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass in the variables as a function parameter:

```
func quiz(allQuestions, num) { /* code here */ }

quiz([{
    question: "How many presidents were members of the Whig party?",
    choices: ["Four", "Three", "Two"],
    correct: 0
}, {
    question: "Who was the first president to be impeached?",
    choices: ["Andrew Jackson", "Andrew Johnson", "Warren Harding"],
    correct: 1
}, {
    question: "How many presidents died during their presidency?",
    choices: ["Four", "Six", "Eight"],
    correct: 2
}], 1);
quiz([{
    question: "Sample text for second quiz?",
    choices: ["Four", "Three", "Two"],
    correct: 0
}, {
    question: "Sample text 2 for second quiz?",
    choices: ["Andrew Jackson", "Andrew Johnson", "Warren Harding"],
    correct: 1
}, {
    question: "Sample text 3?",
    choices: ["Four", "Six", "Eight"],
    correct: 2
}], 2);
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvdaQV?editors=001

Comment: Had to adjust the pen to add the '1' to the buttons of the first quiz: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvaqWP?editors=101